# Spring Integration STS Plugin integration-graph "manual mode"

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-integration

In multiple forum threads, people are talking about a "manual mode" when editing spring-integration xml file in integration-graph tab.

The problem is I'm unable to find a way to access this manual mode and to change the layout of the default provided graph (which is a complete mess).

I tried to change the position of elements but I get a red cross and I can find a button that says switch to manual mode or something like that?

Could someone help ?

My Env : Eclipse 4.4.2 + Spring IDE plugin 3.6.4 .  I also tried with STS 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is "Enable Manual Layout" button on the toolbar: [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot . Exactly what I wanted. You saved my life :).